# Why would an STM32 not execute its program after upload?

Tags: stm32, mbed, st-link

I am attempting to breadboard an **STM32F401** using a 64-pin breakout board. I am able to both connect and upload my program successfully (via **ST-LINK V2** SWD pins), but once uploaded, the program seizes to execute itself.

Oddly enough, I am able to use the st-link debugger and "step" through the program and blink an LED as expected, however, as previously mentioned, outside of using the debugger the program refuses to execute itself.

So after sleeping on this, I woke up and soldered a new chip to a new breakout board to see if I was working with a damaged chip. Since I got the exact same result with a different chip, I am thinking there must be a problem with either the software (unlikely), ST-LINK (unlikely), or the way in which I have wired up the hardware pins (likely?).

I have followed the official ST Nucleo F4 schematics for wiring up the chip for programming, hence why I am kinda stumped with this.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Hardware**:

- ST-LINK V2 (official ST, brand new)
- STM32F401RET6

**Software**:

- MBED v5.14

---

**STM32F401 Breadboard Schematic**

[image: STM32F401 Breadboard Schematic]

**MBED Blink Program**

All this is suppose to do is Blink an LED

```
#include <mbed.h>

DigitalOut myled(PA_5);

int main() {
  myled.write(1);

  while(1) {
    myled.write(1);
    wait_us(100);
    myled.write(0);
    wait_us(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: did you reset the microcontroller after upload? You need to halt it to upload, and after, it needs to be told to boot

Comment: @MarcusMüller what combination of reset/boot buttons do I need to do? hold reset down, then upload, then release? Also, I though the SDW reset pin auto-resets the device after upload

Comment: If you use the PC program from ST to upload using SWD, you need to separately press Run or it will just sit waiting for further commands after flashing the firmware. Other programs may upload and run directly. But your hardware is not perfect either. Reset pin should have 100nF capacitor, and it should not have any pull-ups. The VBAT pin is also unconnected, it should be connected to VCC.

Comment: Is this a debug build or a release build? A debug build might contain some reference to semihosting which might halt the processor in a non-conditional breakpoint which you do not notice during debugging. And your timing might lead to not very well perceivable blinking with just 100 µs on and 10 µs off timing. It'll probably look like the LED is on, just a bit darker than with just setting it to 1. Use something like 500 ms on and off.

Comment: @Justme even after making those changes the program isn't running. How do I manually "press Run"?

Comment: @Arsenal it is `Building in release mode`, and adjusting the wait time to 1000 us still leaves me with an always ON LED.  Its like like there is something wrong with the clock configuration or something... when I comment out all the LED code in the program the LED does not turn on, but when I have the LED code **just in the while loop** the LED will turn on, but no blinking/flashing. So its almost as if the program IS actually executing... this does not make sence

Comment: okay something else I noticed. If I disconnect the ST-LINK, the LED turns off.

Comment: You cannot perceive a LED blinking at 1 ms (you need an oscilloscope for that). Use `myled.write(1);  wait_us(500000);
    myled.write(0);    wait_us(500000);`

Comment: @Arsenal this seemed to work. LED is blinking now. Thank you...

Comment: Forgot to mention; don't push the Boot button. It shorts VCC to GND. It does not set Boot0 pin high.

Comment: @Justme I was actually confused with this button circuit myself... I suppose placing the `boot0` wire between the resistor to GND and VCC is more appropriate?

Comment: At minimum, Boot0 should be always pulled down by the resistor, so that pushbutton will connect Boot0 to VDD.